# How do I grab a random word from a txt file and set it as a variable in Batch

Tags: list, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Sorry if this has been asked before, I couldn't find anything though specifically for this.

I have a list.txt with a new word on each line, like

```
do
re
me
fa
something
somethingelse
```

How can I grab a random word (assuming the list has a random amount of lines)and set it as a %variable%?

I'm pretty sure I would need the "for" command but I've got no idea how to use it lol

Thanks

Edit: my bad I should've specified this is in Windows Batch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: With PowerShell this is trivial `powershell -NoP -C "Get-Content .\file.txt|Get-Random"` could easily be wrapped in a batch. The title should ask for a random line not word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (you'll have to change the path to the file on the third line):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=words.txt"

for /f %%# in (
    'findstr  /r /n "^" "%file%" ^|find /c ":"'
) do (
    set lines=%%#
)

set /a random_line=(%RANDOM%*%lines%/32768)

for /f "usebackq skip=%random_line%" %%# in ("%file%") do (
    set "random_word=%%#"
    goto :break
)   
:break

echo %random_word%
endlocal
```

UPDATE:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "file=words.txt"

for /f %%# in (
    'findstr  /r /n "^" "%file%" ^|find /c ":"'
) do (
    set lines=%%#
)

set /a random_line=random_line=%random% %% %lines%

if random_line==0 (
    set "skip="
) else (
    set "skip=skip=%random_line%"
)

for /f "usebackq %skip%" %%# in ("%file%") do (
    set "random_word=%%#"
    goto :break
)   
:break

echo %random_word%
endlocal
```

Comment: actually just a quick improvement, change the random line part to this and it's much more reliable  `set /a "random_line=%random% %% %lines%"`

Comment: You have to handle the case `random_line=0` differently because `for /F` does unfortunately not accept a `skip=0` option...

Comment: @aschipfl - aah yes, I'll have to add one if condition.

Comment: updated........